# ¿Cómo concatenar cadenas de texto y variables en C?

Tags: c

Buenas noches comunidad.

Estoy realizando un algoritmo en C que basicamente toma un valor y lo multiplica con una contsante, el problema es que no me imprime como lo especifico (la cocantenación está erronea) y no he podido encontrar una solución. Sé que existe la librería iostream, pero tratandose de C no me sirve en lo absoluto. ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Agradezco mucho su colaboración.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int sandwich_1 = 12000;
const int sandwich_2 = 13500;
const int sandwich_3 = 14800;

int main () {
    int cantidad;
    int tipo_sandwich;
    int total;
    cantidad = 0;
    tipo_sandwich = 0;
    total = 0;

    printf ("Bienvenido, por favor ingrese la cantidad de sandwich´s que desea \n");
    scanf ("%d" , & cantidad);
    printf ("Por favor ingrese el tipo de Sandiwch´s que desea \n");
    scanf ("%d", & tipo_sandwich);

    if (cantidad <= 0) {
        printf ("Por favor ingrese una cantidad valida");
    }
    else {
        if (tipo_sandwich == 1) {
            total = sandwich_1 * cantidad;
            printf ("%d El costo total de " , cantidad ,  " %d sandwich es $", total);
        }
        else {
            if (tipo_sandwich == 2) {
                total = sandwich_2 * cantidad;
                printf ("%d El costo total de " , cantidad ,  " %d sandwich es $", total);
            }
            else {
                if (tipo_sandwich == 3) {
                total = sandwich_3 * cantidad;
                printf ("%d El costo total de " , cantidad ,  " %d sandwich es $", total);
                }
                else {
                    printf ("No existe el producto ingresado");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    getch ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola! ¿Puedes colocar que es lo que te imprime y cómo esperas que lo imprima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero: 
No esta mal que separes `int cantidad;` y abajo le añadas un valor, `cantidad =0;` pero para optimizar tu codigo podrías declarar el valor dentro de la misma variable, quedando así: **`int cantidad=0;`**

Segundo: Tampoco es que estas haciendo mal uso de las condicionantes, pero manejarlo de esa manera puede ser un poco confuso cuando te encuentres con códigos mas extensos.
Trata de irlos acomodando de la sig. manera

En lugar de usar:

```
else {
 if (condición) { 
 }
}
```

Puede acortarlo de esta manera:

```
else if (condicion) 
{
}
```

Tercero: Aquí se encuentra el principal problema.

`printf ("%d El costo total de " , cantidad ,  " %d sandwich es $", total);`

Estas haciendo mal uso de **`%d`** los **%d** son los marcadores de donde sera expuesta la variable/solución a exponer. 
Si lo pones de esa manera el código resultante seria el siguiente (por poner un ejemplo):

**1 El costo total de 12000 de sandwich es $**

Para que quede cuerda la oración tendrías que acomodar las lineas de esta manera:

`printf("El costo total de %d", cantidad , " sandwich es $%d", total);`

Y ya pasaria a decir: **"El costo total de 1 sandwich es 12000"**

Aquí todavia no terminamos, ahora, el por que no se muestran los resultados se debe a la sintaxis que manejas en el **printf**.

NO puedes separar comillas, tu printf tendria que quedar de la sig manera:

`printf(""El costo total de %d sandwich es $%d", cantidad, total);`

Toda tu oración tiene que quedar dentro de las comillas, los **%d** son por orden, entonces si tienes 2 en una sola oración al final de las comillas debes ponerlos según el orden que quieras que aparezcan, en este caso: primero ***cantidad*** y luego ***total***.

Haz lo mismo en los otros **printf** y tendrás corregido el problema :)

Por ultimo te adjunto como debería quedar el código si añadieras lo que mencione anteriormente.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int sandwich_1 = 12000;
const int sandwich_2 = 13500;
const int sandwich_3 = 14800;

int main () {
   int cantidad=0;
   int tipo_sandwich=0;
   int total=0;

   printf ("Bienvenido, por favor ingrese la cantidad de sandwich´s que desea \n");
   scanf ("%d" , & cantidad);
   printf ("Por favor ingrese el tipo de Sandiwch´s que desea \n");
   scanf ("%d", & tipo_sandwich);

   if (cantidad <= 0)
   {
       printf ("Por favor ingrese una cantidad valida");
   }
   else if (tipo_sandwich == 1) 
   {
       total = sandwich_1 * cantidad;
       printf ("El costo total de %d sandwich es $%d " , cantidad,total);
   }

   else if (tipo_sandwich == 2)
   {
       total = sandwich_2 * cantidad;
       printf ("El costo total de %d sandwich es $%d " , cantidad,total);
   }

   else if (tipo_sandwich == 3) 
   {
   total = sandwich_3 * cantidad;
   printf ("El costo total de %d sandwich es $%d " , cantidad,total);
   }
   else 
   {
      printf ("No existe el producto ingresado");
   }

return 0;
```

}

Comment: *pero para optimizar tu codigo podrías declarar el valor dentro de la misma variable*...  Ambas formas son eficientes en tiempo de ejecución, debido a que, generan el mismo código ASM (lo puedes comprobar compilando con alguna opción que tenga tu compilador). En fin, deberías de especificar a que tipo de optimización te refieres.

Answer (score 4):

La firma de la función `printf` es:

```
int printf( const char *format, ... );
```

El parámetro `format` es una cadena de caracteres con el texto a mostrar, el parámetro elipsis (`...`) son los valores que se substituirán en la cadena de caracteres, así que la manera correcta de imprimir dos valores numéricos es la siguiente:

```
// Primera substitución__                 __ Segunda substitución
//                       \               /
//                        |              |
//                        v              v
printf("El costo total de %d sandwich es %d", cantidad, total);
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                      \                            \____ (Elipsis) Valores de substitución.
//                       \
//                        \_______ Texto a mostrar.
```